# How to know the camera have captured the clear image in the iOS?

Tags: ios, camera, focus, computer-vision

I'm doing real-time image analysis which is capturing by camera in iOS(ipad or iphone).
Actually i just want to analysis the image which is clear imaging, if the image is not clear ,i want to discard it.
It's known that the image is not clear when the camera is not focus.

Now my question is :

1. Whether the iOS can give some indicator the camera have finished focus?
2. If i move the iPad camera to aim to some object,How i can get the indicator the object image is clear?

In my projcet, i use the AVCaptureDevice to autofocus object. It provide the interface "isAdjustingFocus"
to indicator the camera is focusing. But it is not enough to decide the image is clear.
i find when i move the camera then stop, the iOS have some delay to start focus. So When 
i move the ipad ,the image is blurry ,but the indicator is still indicate that it isn't focusing.So i can't get the mode to know the image is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the point spread function to estimate blur, and by extension focus, of the image.

Comment: Could you elaborate/share links on this subject? Thanks